# Using Linq to bring back last 3,4...n orders for every customer

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have a database with customers orders.
I want to use Linq (to EF) to query the db to bring back the last(most recent) 3,4...n orders  for every customer.

Note:
Customer 1 may have just made 12 orders in the last hr; but customer 2 may not have made any since last week.

I cant for the life of me work out how to write query in linq (lambda expressions) to get the data set back.

Any good ideas?

**Edit:**
Customers and orders is a simplification. The table I am querying is actually a record of outbound messages to various web services. It just seemed easer to describe as customers and orders. The relationship is the same.
I am building a task that checks the last n messages for each web service to see if there were any failures. We are wanting a semi real time Health status of the webservices.

@CoreySunwold
My table Looks a bit like this:
**MessageID, WebserviceID, SentTime, Status, Message, Error,**

Or from a customer/order context if it makes it easer:
**OrderID, CustomerID, StatusChangedDate, Status, WidgetName, Comments**

**Edit 2:**
I eventually worked out something
(Hat tip to @StephenChung who basically came up with the exact same, but in classic linq)

`var q = myTable.Where(d => d.EndTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))

                                 .GroupBy(g => g.ConfigID)

                                 .Select(g =>new
                                             {
                                                 ConfigID = g.Key,
                                                 Data = g.OrderByDescending(d => d.EndTime)
                                                 .Take(3).Select(s => new 
                                                                      { 
                                                                        s.Status,
                                                                        s.SentTime 
                                                                      })
                                             }).ToList();`

It does take a while to execute. So I am not sure if this is the most efficient expression.

Comment: Do you have anything so far? Also can you tell us anything about the tables you are querying against? If you have a column with an identity value this should be pretty easy.

Comment: @CoreySunwold I have put in what my table kinda looks like.

Comment: @CoreySunwold I have also put what I have as a partial solution. I am not sure how optimal it is though. It is basically the same as what @StephenChung came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give the last 3 orders of each customer (if having orders at all):

```
from o in db.Orders
group o by o.CustomerID into g
select new {
  CustomerID=g.Key,
  LastOrders=g.OrderByDescending(o => o.TimeEntered).Take(3).ToList()
}
```

However, I suspect this will force the database to return the *entire* Orders table before picking out the last 3 for each customer.  Check the SQL generated.

If you need to optimize, you'll have to manually construct a SQL to only return up to the last 3, then make it into a view.

Comment: This is basiclly the same as what I came up with eventually. But in lambda syntax. So Up vote from me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SelectMany for this purpose:

```
customers.SelectMany(x=>x.orders.OrderByDescending(y=>y.Date).Take(n)).ToList();
```

Comment: needs an orderby to work, i've never used this with linq to sql or EF, i might try it.

Comment: @Paul Creasey, why order by? I have it in query, I didn't test it by linq2sql just guess it works, but it doesn't work in linq2nhibernate (at least nhibernate 2.x)

Comment: I tried to use this, but I couldn't get the .SelectMany() syntax correct. I have put up a sample table layout. If you could update what you have to work with that, it would be seriously awesome.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I know it'll work with regular collections but don't know about EF.

```
yourCollection.OrderByDescending(item=>item.Date).Take(n);
```

Comment: this just gives the last n orders for any customer

Comment: Yep, you're right. I will upvote the SelectMany approach below - it should do it for every customer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var orders = orders.Where(x => x.CustomerID == 1).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).Take(4);
```

This will take last 4 orders. Specific query depends on your table / entity structure.

Btw: You can take x as a order. So you can read it like: Get orders where order.CustomerID is equal to 1, OrderThem by order.Date and take first 4 'rows'.

Comment: should be OrderByDescending, then this will work, but only for 1 customer

Answer (score 0):

```
var ordersByCustomer = 
db.Customers.Select(c=>c.Orders.OrderByDescending(o=>o.OrderID).Take(n));
```

This will return the orders grouped by customer.

Answer (score -1):

Somebody might correct me here, but i think doing this is linq with a single query is probably very difficult if not impossible. I would use a store procedure and something like this

```
select 
    *
    ,RANK() OVER  (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY o.order_time DESC) AS 'RANK'
from 
    customers c 
inner join 
    order o
on 
    o.cust_id = c.id
where 
    RANK < 10 -- this is "n"
```

I've not used this syntax for a while so it might not be quite right, but if i understand the question then i think this is the best approach.

Comment: this is not difficult at all with linq. it is even simpler.

Comment: With linq yes, but i'm not so sure with linq to sql of EF, but i can't be bothered to test it.